# add site url only if it is missing

Tags: php, preg-replace

I need to alter the text in some places which was having missing site url.

Suppose I have a big html code, in that code some places the site url is missing, but some places it has.

Example : `/blog/images/image.png` need to alter `http://www.domain.com/blog/images/image.png`

So I have tried following code,

```
$html=preg_replace('%/blog/%','http://www.domain.com/blog/',$html);
```

But with this code it alter the following lines as well,

```
http://www.domain.com/blog/images/image.png -> http://www.domain.com/http://www.domain.com/blog/images/image.png
```

How should I skip that ?

Basically I need to add the site url(http://www.domain.com/) to some places only if it is missing.

Comment: Declare global variable $base_url = "http://www.domain.com/" and use $base_url wherever you want

Comment: @Sagar this html text is coming from external source, I am not the one who construct it, that is why I need to alter it.

Comment: @JanithChinthana please check out my answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Its little tricky. Just remove the `http://www.domain.com/` from url and add `http://www.domain.com/`manually to url.

Try

```
$html = "http://www.domain.com/".str_ireplace('http://www.domain.com/','',$html);
```

OR

Find the values where `http://www.domain.com/http://www.domain.com/` add two times and replace it with `http://www.domain.com/`

Try

```
$html = preg_replace('%/blog/%','http://www.domain.com/blog/',$html);
$html = str_ireplace('http://www.domain.com/http://www.domain.com/','http://www.domain.com/',$html);
```

OR (solution by @anonymous)

```
$html = preg_replace('@(http://www.domain.com)?/blog@iU', 'http://www.domain.com/blog', $html)
```

Comment: It makes sense, I will try it

Comment: or you could do `preg_replace('@(http://www.domain.com)?/blog@iU', 'http://www.domain.com/blog', $html)`

Comment: @anonymous you could add this as an answer, this is what I really looking for

Comment: @anonymous I have updated my answer with your solution.