# add site url if it is missing

Tags: php, regex, preg-replace

First of this was related to [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31554595/add-site-url-only-if-it-is-missing) I asked one year before and now I have need to change the code bit with new `https` site.

Basically I need to add the site url if it is missing as I describe in the previous question.

Eg : `/blog/images/image.png` need to alter `http://www.example.com/blog/images/image.png`

@anonymous had given the answer as bellow,

```
$html = preg_replace('@(http://www.example.com)?/blog@iU', 'http://www.example.com/blog', $html);
```

But now the problem is I have `https` links also, so when ever I have `https` link it is adding `http://www.example.com/blog` in between with above code.

Eg : `https://www.example.com/blog/images/image.png` converts to `https://www.example.com/http://www.example.com/blog/images/image.png`.

Basically now I need to check both `https://www.example.com` or `http://www.example.com` before the `/blog`, if non of them were available just add  `http://www.example.com` in front of `/blog`. Hope I am clear enough with the issue.

How should I do that ?

Apologies about my regex knowledge.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add an optional `s` and escape the dots in the pattern, and then use `preg_replace_callback` to check if Group 1 matched. If yes, take the `$1` value, else, hardcode the replacement:

```
$html = preg_replace_callback('@(https?://www\.example\.com)?/blog@i', function($m) { 
    return empty($m[1]) ? 'http://www.example.com/blog' : $m[1] . "/blog";
}, $html);
```

See the [PHP demo](https://ideone.com/2B2ryB).

Note you do not need the `U` modifier here. After `/blog`, you may add `(?=/|$)` to make sure the `blog` is only matched when it is a whole subpart of the path (to avoid matching on `/blogs` or `/blogging/`).

Answer (score 1):

Make it replace any `/blog` substrings which are not preceded with protocol-host part:

```
$html = preg_replace('@(?<!https://www\.example\.com)(?<!http://www\.example\.com)/blog@iU', 'http://www.example.com/blog', $html);
```

The regex itself is:

```
(?<!https://www\.example\.com)(?<!http://www\.example\.com)/blog
```

It checks for `http://www.example.com` and `https://www.example.com` prefixes using negative lookahead. Note that we have to use two separate lookaheads because the prefixes have different length.

Demo: https://regex101.com/r/0ERgu7/1